# Is there a shorter way to overwrite properties of an original entity object to a current entity object?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

For example, I have:

```
originalItem.Property1 = currentItem.Property1;
originalItem.Property2 = currentItem.Property2;
originalItem.Property3 = currentItem.Property3;
originalItem.Property4 = currentItem.Property4;
```

The properties will also change if the currentItem's property's value is different from that of originalItem's.

Any shortcuts here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this via [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(VS.80).aspx).

Read the properties of both the instances and assign them with the help of reflection.

Here's some code..

```
    public static void AssignSourceToDestination(Object source, ref Object destination)
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> sourceProps = source.GetProperties();
        IList<PropertyInfo> destProps = destination.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in destProps)
        {
            if (property.CanWrite)
            {
                PropertyInfo sourceProp = sourceProps.Where(p => p.Name.Equals(property.Name) &&
                    p.PropertyType.Equals(property.PropertyType) && p.CanRead).First();
                if (null != sourceProp)
                    property.SetValue(destination, sourceProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(this Object me)
    {
        return me.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();
    }
```